# Regex divide with upper-case

Tags: python, regex, string, split, uppercase

I would like to replace strings like `'HDMWhoSomeThing'` to `'HDM Who Some Thing'` with regex.

So I would like to extract words which starts with an upper-case letter or consist of upper-case letters only. Notice that in the string `'HDMWho'` the last upper-case letter is in the fact the first letter of the word `Who` - and should not be included in the word `HDM`.

What is the correct regex to achieve this goal? I have tried many regex' similar to `[A-Z][a-z]+` but without success. The `[A-Z][a-z]+` gives me `'Who Some Thing'` - without `'HDM'` of course.

Any ideas?
Thanks,
Rukki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import re
from collections import deque

pattern = r'([A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z](?=[a-z]|$))'
chunks = deque(re.split(pattern, 'HDMWhoSomeMONKEYThingXYZ'))

result = []
while len(chunks):
  buf = chunks.popleft()
  if len(buf) == 0:
    continue
  if re.match(r'^[A-Z]$', buf) and len(chunks):
    buf += chunks.popleft()
  result.append(buf)

print ' '.join(result)
```

Output:

```
HDM Who Some MONKEY Thing XYZ
```

Judging by lines of code, this task is a much more natural fit with [`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
pattern = r'([A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z][a-z]*)'
print ' '.join(re.findall(pattern, 'HDMWhoSomeMONKEYThingX'))
```

Output:

```
HDM Who Some MONKEY Thing X
```

Comment: I think this one runs into the problem with all-caps words in the middle of the string as well. The re.split called on the string 'HDMWhoSomeMONKEYThing' will give you [HDM, Who, SomeMONKEY, Thing]

Answer (score 2):

Try to split with this regular expression:

```
/(?=[A-Z][a-z])/
```

And if your regular expression engine does not support splitting empty matches, try this regular expression to put spaces between the words:

```
/([A-Z])(?![A-Z])/
```

Replace it with `" $1"` (space plus match of the first group). Then you can split at the space.

Comment: I am using Python. Unfortunately pattern (?=[A-Z][a-z]) matches nothing and pattern ([A-Z])(?![A-Z]) gives "W S T "  :(

Comment: @Rukki Odds: I wrote you have to replace the matches of `([A-Z])(?![A-Z])` with a space followed by the match of the first group to separate the words. And then you can use `\s+` to split the words.

Comment: `([A-Z])(?![A-Z])` won't help if there is an all-caps word in the middle of the string: eg on 'HDMWhoSomeMONKEYThing' will only match W,S and T in 'Who', 'Some' and 'Thing'

Answer (score 2):

one liner :

' '.join(a or b for a,b in re.findall('([A-Z][a-z]+)|(?:([A-Z]*)(?=[A-Z]))',s))

using regexp

([A-Z][a-z]+)|(?:([A-Z]*)(?=[A-Z]))

Comment: This won't match a one-character uppercase word at the end of the string. Doesn't matter for the OP's application of inserting spaces between them, but might be a problem if something else needs to be done with all the words.

Answer (score 1):

May be '[A-Z]*?[A-Z][a-z]+'?

**Edit:** This seems to work: [A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+

```
import re

def find_stuff(str):
  p = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{2,}(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]+')
  m = p.findall(str)
  result = ''
  for x in m:
    result += x + ' '
  print result

find_stuff('HDMWhoSomeThing')
find_stuff('SomeHDMWhoThing')
```

Prints out:

> HDM Who Some Thing
>
> Some HDM Who Thing

Comment: Almost correct - but it gives "HDMWho Some Thing " instead od "HDM Who Some Thing"

Comment: my exact code:
    str = 'HDMWhoSomeThing'\n
    p = re.compile('[A-Z]*?[A-Z][a-z]+')\n
    m = p.findall('HDMWhoSomeThing')\n
    result = ''\n
    for x in m:\n
        result += x + ' '\n
    print result\n

I have changed end of the lines with \n

Comment: Misses a one-character uppercase word anywhere in the string: 'HDMWhoSomeAThingA' won't match either 'A' (change the {2,} to a + and it will grab the one-character words)

Answer (score 1):

So 'words' in this case are:

1. Any number of uppercase letters - unless the last uppercase letter is followed by a lowercase letter.
2. One uppercase letter followed by any number of lowercase letters.

so try:

`([A-Z]+(?![a-z])|[A-Z][a-z]*)`

The first alternation includes a negative lookahead (?![a-z]), which handles the boundary between an all-caps word and an initial caps word.