# Regex for matching only capitalized words stuck together (i.e. not separated by whitespace)

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have a long list of strings which are all random words, all of them capitalized, such as `'Pomegranate'` and `'Yellow Banana'`. However, some of them are stuck together, like so: `'AppleOrange'`. There are no special characters or digits.

What I need is a regular expression on Python that matches `'Apple'` and `'Orange'` separately, but not `'Pomegranate'` or `'Yellow'`.

As expected, I'm very new to this, and I've only managed to write `r"(?<!\s)([A-Z][a-z]*)"`... But that still matches `'Yellow'` and `'Pomegranate'` . How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they all start with an uppercase char and optional lowercase chars, you can make use of lookarounds and an alternation to match both variations

```
(?<=[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]*|[A-Z][a-z]*(?=[A-Z])
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=[a-z])` Assert a-z to the left
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` match A-Z and optional chars a-z
- `|` or
- `[A-Z][a-z]*` match A-Z and optional chars a-z
- `(?=[A-Z])` Assert A-Z to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JQGNtY/1)

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=[a-z])[A-Z][a-z]*|[A-Z][a-z]*(?=[A-Z])"
s = ("AppleOrange\nPomegranate Yellow Banana")

print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['Apple', 'Orange']
```

---

Another option could be getting out of the way what you don't want by matching it, and use a capture group for what you want to keep and remove the empty entries from the result:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-z]*(?!\S)|([A-Z][a-z]*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o9MNRZ/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w9YmBg)

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<!\S)[A-Z][a-z]*(?!\S)|([A-Z][a-z]*)"
s = ("AppleOrange\nPomegranate Yellow Banana")

print([x for x in re.findall(pattern, s) if x])
```

Comment: Wow, that's a tad more complex than what I was expecting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This work:

```
import re
from collections import deque

pattern = r'([A-Z]{2,}(?=[A-Z]|$)|[A-Z](?=[a-z]|$))'
chunks = deque(re.split(pattern, 'AppleOrange'))

result = []
while len(chunks):
  buf = chunks.popleft()
  if len(buf) == 0:
    continue
  if re.match(r'^[A-Z]$', buf) and len(chunks):
    buf += chunks.popleft()
  result.append(buf)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['Apple', 'Orange']
```

Check the OP [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273462/regex-divide-with-upper-case)